# dll MATLAB, dll DBMS, blob?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, matlab

Is it possible to make a library or dll that can be used in both MATLAB and any DBMS like SQL Server (with .net), Oracle, etc...

I want to process data in Matlab or SQL and use  this common library.
Is it possible to use a blob and then MATLAB  read that?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure you can transfer data from at least Oracle using a blob to any program outside the database. That program has to be able to interpret the blob and most likely it has to be able to build some memory structure from it. Most memory structures rely on pointers to memory locations and this will be hard to store in a database because memory location will vary and the database storage is consistent. For be this sounds like back to the 70's - 80's.

Apart from that, you most probably want to do some analysis on that data. For the data to transfer to your client, the database has to dig it all up. That costs time, the same for the transfer to the client, especially when large volumes are in place. By the time the client has the data to be able to start the analysis, the database - at least in Oracle - has completed that same analysis. Disadvantage of that solution is that it is database depended, advantage is that it is the best performant solution.